# Installing webpart

Tags: 2007, web-part, administration

I'm a beginner on Sharepoint and I want to ask if I can install webpart at our subsite. I only have access to our subsite's MOSS.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want install web-part to site only having access to sub-site?

Answer (score 2):

If the web part is not available in your Site's Web Part Gallery, you will need to have the administrator of your SharePoint farm install the web part solution so that it is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

To add a webpart as a beginer I would recommend wspbuilder, It will add and deploy the webpart for you, the only task left is to do the following:

You need to be admin to do the following! (adding webpart to page)
On the page that you want to add the webpart goto:

Click: Site Action

then

Click: Site Settings

under Site Collection Administration 
select: Go to top level site settings

under Galleries
select: Web Parts

Click on "New"

then select the webpart you want, tick "Overwrite if file already exists?"

now its added to the list you then need to:
Click on: Site Action

then

Click: Edit Page

select an area that you want the webpart to be in and click "Add a webpart".

Scroll through the webpart list zones to find your one, once found select it and add. You can now exit edit mode and you should be able to see your new webpart on the page ;)

Instead of wspbuilder you can do it manually using stsadm "stsadm -o addsolution -filename "" " and then you have to deploy the solution either from stsadm or sharepoint central admin select "operations" then select "Solution managment" and then find the solution that says the webpart name you have given it and its status should say "not deployed". Once you hve found it select it and click on "Deploy Solution".

this is wspbuilder:
http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Hope this is informative and helps you out :)